# Can I search for mods by author?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-one

In the Special Edition on Xbox One, is there a way for me to search for all of the mods created by a single author? As a console player, I find the list a bit overwhelming. I cannot decide which mods I should download, so I wanted to limit my selection to just the best few authors.

Comment: I would maybe suggest searching here: http://steamcommunity.com/app/72850/workshop/ and then trying to find the specific mod that you want on Xbox that matches up with what you find on steam.

Comment: It would seem that you cannot search by mod authors on the mods.bethesda.net page, which I find foolish on their part...

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: Yes, click on the Author's name**

I thought this was always possible, however, it may be that it's a more recent adjustment to their UI.

Let's go through this step-by-step:

1. Go to the Skyrim page with your favorite filters set... like Most Popular/Last Week, XBox One.  Looks like this:

[image: SkyrimModsFavoriteFiltersSet]

2. Find a mod by the author, click on his name... let's say Arthmoor, because he's pretty awesome, and...

[image: Click on Authors Name]

3. Just like that, you see his mods:

[image: Arthmoor Skyrim Mods]

Obviously, you have to know about one of his or her mods first, but once you find one, the rest is simple.  It may be possible to save that as a bookmark for future reference, but we'll leave that as an exercise for someone else.